# Can the son of a kohen born to a non-observant giyores be called up to the first Aliya

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, kohen-priest, torah-reading

Can a son of a kohen that married a non-observant giyores be called up to the Torah  for the first Aliya?

Comment: A child born of the union between a Kohen and someone prohibited to Kohanim is a hallal. A hallal is not traditionally given the first aliyah.

Comment: She's a halachic זונה who is forbidden to a Kohen and her son from a Kohen is a חלל so presumably he cannot

Comment: If there's no Kohain present, sure, just like any Yisrarel or Levi

Answer (score 3):

As @Deuteronomy and others have commented, see [here, Shulchan Aruch HaRav](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/the-status-of-a-kohen-who-is-a-challal/#_ftnref4)

> Any child who was born from parents who were in a Biblically Kehuna
> prohibited relationship, whether within wedlock or out of wedlock, is
> defined as a Challal. Meaning, that if a man who is a Kohen has a
> child with a woman to whom he is Biblically prohibited in marrying due
> to his status of priesthood, then any offspring born from that union
> is defined as a Challal. For example, if a Kohen had a child with  a woman who is Halachically defined as a Zoneh...."

and

> A gentile is considered a Zonah.

So, he is not normally given the first aliyah.